# Make pretty nested hierarchy from the input array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grouping

I'm trying to make build nested hierarchy from the defined input data, and I`m faced some problem with the deep level hierarchy. So, as an input there is array of objects, looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        parentId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        parentId: 3,
    },
    ...
]
```

Every element has his own id and parentId. 
As outcome, I want to have the structure, grouped by the parent id's, smth like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    sub: [
        {
          id: 2,
          parentId: 1,
          sub: [
              {
                  id: 3,
                  parenId: 2,
              },
              ....
          ],
        },
    ],
}
```

So, the problem is how to build algorithm that will recursively goes through this input data, and build such structured outcome? When I know the level of hierarchy, I could build algorithm with defined level of nested loops, but the problem is with unknown number of deeper.

Comment: Would be cool if you then get data like this, `{id: 1, parentId: 2}, {id: 2, parentId: 1}`

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yeah, but it will be other side problem :)

Comment: could this help? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/

Comment: You need to look into recursion.

Comment: @trincot - looks like the accepted answer only works up to depths of 2 nodes.

Comment: @trincot The sesond answer there is doing the thing! Thanks!